# Error when does not select data from DDL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had this message

> *Input string was not in a correct format*

when inserting values into the database. When I checked I have DDL but I did not select value from it so this message appeared, although I make this column in the database to allow NULL value.

```
protected void BT_submit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string File = "~/CvFiles/" + FU_CV.FileName;
    if (FU_CV.FileBytes.Length > 4194304)
    {
        modalpopup.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        app.AddApplicant(txt_Mname.Text, Convert.ToInt32(DDL_Dept.SelectedValue));
    }
}

private void loadDepts()
{
    DDL_Dept.DataSource = d.GetAll();
    DDL_Dept.Items.Clear();
    DDL_Dept.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    DDL_Dept.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-All-", "NULL"));
    DDL_Dept.DataValueField = "id";
    DDL_Dept.DataTextField = "name";
    DDL_Dept.DataBind();
}
 public bool AddApplicant(string MiddleName, int Dept_ID)
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Insert_IntoApplicantforuser");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", MiddleName);


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept_ID", Dept_ID);


    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter paramter1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@AppID", SqlDbType.Int);
    paramter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    bool rowaffected;
    rowaffected = DBHelper.Instance().Insert(cmd);
    if (rowaffected == false)
    {
        AppID = (int)paramter1.Value;

    }
    return rowaffected;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check, if DDL_Dept.SelectedValue is a string representation of `int`. Use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method:

```
if (FU_CV.FileBytes.Length > 4194304)
{
    modalpopup.Show();
}
else
{
    int dept;
    if  (int.TryParse(DDL_Dept.SelectedValue, out dept))
        app.AddApplicant(txt_Mname.Text, dept);
    else 
        app.AddApplicant(txt_Mname.Text, -1); //or whatever there should be for you
}
```

Comment: AddApplicant have the int variable that have the value from DDl so when I used NULL error appeared

Comment: that cannot convert int to NULL

Comment: @Egydeveloper what do you mean by "convert int to NULL"? Can you show your method AddApplicant?

Comment: As in your method last argument is int, you should replace null with 0 (or -1&) - it is up to you and your db logic (maybe you have triggers?)

Comment: this error appeared The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Applicants_Departments". The conflict occurred in database "ElarabyHospital", table "dbo.Departments", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated